# RSelenium error with phantom

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, rselenium

I am running the following code and am getting an error which I do not know how to resolve:

```
require(RSelenium)
startServer()
pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantom")
remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

But, when I run the following code, with "phantomjs", it runs fine:

```
require(RSelenium)
startServer()
pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()
remDr$close()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try copying `phantomjs.exe` onto your path and attempting option 2 without the `pJS <- phantom()` line....

Comment: @mnel I tried doing that but that doesn't work either.